# How selectively remove characters from elements in a data frame?

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data frame shown below:

```
Sample <- c("A1.1","B1.1","A1.2","B1.2","A2.1","B2.1","A2.2","B2.2")
X <- c(1,1,2,4,3,5,3,2)
Y <- c(2,3,1,5,4,6,2,2)
df <- data.frame(Sample, X, Y)
df
  Sample X Y
1   A1.1 1 2
2   B1.1 1 3
3   A1.2 2 1
4   B1.2 4 5
5   A2.1 3 4
6   B2.1 5 6
7   A2.2 3 2
8   B2.2 2 2
```

I want to remove the first and third character as well as the decimal from each element under `Sample`. For example A1.1 -> 1 or A2.1 -> 2.

Is there a way to do this using `gsub`?

Comment: So just `substr` to get the second character? Or are there more complicated cases?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gsub` with the regex alternation `^[A-Z]+|\\.[0-9]+$`:

```r
df$Sample <- gsub("^[A-Z]+|\\.[0-9]+$", "", df$Sample)
df

  Sample X Y
1      1 1 2
2      1 1 3
3      1 2 1
4      1 4 5
5      2 3 4
6      2 5 6
7      2 3 2
8      2 2 2
```

As one of the comments points out, if the width of all your sample values be always fixed at 4 characters, you could just substring out the second character.  Note that the `sub` approach above is robust to samples such as `AB12.123`.

Comment: @AnilGoyal What happens with a sample input like `A1.10` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` but why not just use `substr` to extract the character you do want:

```
df$Sample <- substr(df$Sample,2,2)
df
  Sample X Y
1      1 1 2
2      1 1 3
3      1 2 1
4      1 4 5
5      2 3 4
6      2 5 6
7      2 3 2
8      2 2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a plethora of answers, I recommend you view some [documentation of regular expressions](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html)

```r
Sample <- c("A1.1","B1.1","A1.2","B1.2","A2.1","B2.1","A2.2","B2.2")
X <- c(1,1,2,4,3,5,3,2)
Y <- c(2,3,1,5,4,6,2,2)
df <- data.frame(Sample, X, Y)

df$Sample2 <- gsub("(.)(.)\\.(.)", "\\2", df$Sample)
df
#>   Sample X Y Sample2
#> 1   A1.1 1 2       1
#> 2   B1.1 1 3       1
#> 3   A1.2 2 1       1
#> 4   B1.2 4 5       1
#> 5   A2.1 3 4       2
#> 6   B2.1 5 6       2
#> 7   A2.2 3 2       2
#> 8   B2.2 2 2       2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: What happens when the major or minor sample numbers become larger than 9 (i.e. become 2 digits or more)?

Comment: you can add a `+` to the last capture group to express there may be multiple. I.e.  `"(.)(.)\\.(.+)"`. Again, there are so many ways to approach regular expressions, which is why if we don't know the full context of your problem, we might not give you a fully accurate solution. I strongly encourage you to learn from the link in my answer to help formulate a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `tidyr::extract` here. We first create 3 capture groups and turn two unwanted ones into `NA`s (first and third) and extract the second one:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  extract(Sample, c(NA, "Sample", NA), "([A-Z]+)(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)")

  Sample X Y
1   A1.1 1 2
2   B1.1 1 3
3   A1.2 2 1
4   B1.2 4 5
5   A2.1 3 4
6   B2.1 5 6
7   A2.2 3 2
8   B2.2 2 2
```